# How to add spine arrows AND offset the spine

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can do either one of these separately, but not together. I think the question comes down to: after offsetting spines in a Matplotlib figure, how does one find the spine bounds in a coordinate system that can be used to plot arrowheads on the ends of the spines?

[image: code result]

The arrows are (obviously) not aligned with the spines.

The code for the arrowheads is from here https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/spines/centered_spines_with_arrows.html

My simplified code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

spine_offset = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)
ax.plot(a, np.sin(a) + 1)

ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.left.set_position(('outward', spine_offset))
ax.spines.bottom.set_position(('outward', spine_offset))

ax.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 1, "^k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
```

Comment: The offset spines are no longer at x=0, y=0 in data space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `set_position(('outward', spine_offset))` the offset is measured in points (1/72 of an inch, similar to how fonts are measured, e.g. a 12 point font).

## using a distance in "axes coordinates"

Instead of `'outward'`, you can also use `'axes'` coordinates: 0 at the bottom  (left), 1 at the top (right). As usually the plot isn't square, to get a visual equal distance, you can convert the x-offset to the y-offset taking the aspect ratio of the bounding box into account.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_offset = 0.02
y_offset = x_offset / ax.get_window_extent().height * ax.get_window_extent().width

a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
ax.plot(np.sin(5 * a), np.sin(6 * a))
ax.set_facecolor('lightsalmon')  # set a color to visualize the offset

ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.left.set_position(('axes', -x_offset))
ax.spines.bottom.set_position(('axes', -y_offset))
ax.plot(1, -y_offset, ">k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
ax.plot(-x_offset, 1, "^k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib: setting offset for spine arrows]

## Converting "points" to "axes coordinates"

Alternatively, you can convert from points to pixels, and from pixels back to axes coordinates. There are 72 points in an inch, and the figure's dpi tells how many pixels there are in an inchh,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

spine_offset_points = 5
spine_offset_pixels = fig.dpi * spine_offset_points / 72.0
x_offset, y_offset = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform((spine_offset_pixels, spine_offset_pixels)) \
                     - ax.transAxes.inverted().transform((0, 0))

a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
ax.plot(np.sin(3 * a), np.sin(8 * a))
ax.set_facecolor('violet')

ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.left.set_position(('outward', spine_offset_points))
ax.spines.bottom.set_position(('outward', spine_offset_points))
ax.plot(1, -y_offset, ">k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
ax.plot(-x_offset, 1, "^k", transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: converting points to axes coordinates]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could place arrow symbols as text using [a transform with an added offset](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/transoffset.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy

spine_offset = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)
ax.plot(a, np.sin(a) + 1)

ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.left.set_position(('outward', spine_offset))
ax.spines.bottom.set_position(('outward', spine_offset))

# text offsets are equal to the spines offsets with the inverted sign
y_text_transform = offset_copy(ax.transAxes, units='points', x=-spine_offset, fig=fig)
x_text_transform = offset_copy(ax.transAxes, units='points', y=-spine_offset, fig=fig)

arrow_symbol = '\u25B2'

# y-arrow
ax.text(0, 1, arrow_symbol, transform=y_text_transform,
        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

# x-arrow
ax.text(1, 0, arrow_symbol, transform=x_text_transform,
        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
        rotation=-90)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]